# Libgdx Sprite.draw() won't draw anything

Tags: android, libgdx, sprite, draw

I'm making a game for Android only.
I am using Libgdx as the framework of a game I'm working on and I'm having trouble drawing sprites. The regular SpriteBatch.draw() works fine, but the Sprite.draw() won't work.
Here's the code of my main class:

```
 private OrthographicCamera camera;
    private Texture currentBackground;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private Bunker bunker;
    private AssetManagerWrapper assetsManager = new AssetManagerWrapper();
    private Turret turret;

    @Override
    public void create() {
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        camera.setToOrtho(false, C.WIDTH_TARGET_RESOLUTION, C.HEIGHT_TARGET_RESOLUTION);
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        assetsManager.loadGFX();
        assetsManager.finishLoading();
        createBunker();
        currentBackground = assetsManager.get(AssetsPaths.Gfx.Background.CITY_DAY);
    }

    private void createBunker() {
        bunker = new Bunker(assetsManager.get(AssetsPaths.Gfx.Bunker.BUNKER, Texture.class));
        turret = new Turret(assetsManager.get(AssetsPaths.Gfx.Bunker.TURRET, Texture.class), bunker.getCenterX(), (int) (bunker.getY() + bunker.getHeight() - 10));
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        camera.update();
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        drawGFX();
    }

    private void drawGFX() {
        batch.begin();
        batch.draw(currentBackground, 0, 0);
        bunker.draw(batch);
        batch.end();
    }


    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        assetsManager.dispose();
    }
```

The Bunker class extends class called GameObject which extends Sprite.
For some reason this line:

```
bunker.draw(batch);
```

Won't draw the sprite. But if I change it to:

```
batch.draw(bunker.getTexture(), bunker.getX(), bunker.getY());
```

It works perfect. I know I can continue using this way but I'm afraid it might be less efficient for reasons I'm not aware of.

The line:

```
batch.draw(currentBackground, 0, 0);
```

Works perfect too.

Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
I changed the bunker object position to x=0 and y=0.
This is the print of getVertices():
0.0,
0.0,
-1.7014117E38,
0.0,
0.0,
0.0,
5.9,
-1.7014117E38,
0.0,
0.0,
100.0,
59.0,
-1.7014117E38,
0.0,
0.0,
100.0,
0.0,
-1.7014117E38,
0.0,
0.0,

I didn't really understand the values but seems the sprite is not drawn outside.

The Bunker class just extends the GameObject class:

```
public class GameObject extends Sprite {

    public GameObject(Texture image, int x, int y) {
        setTexture(image);
        setBounds(x, y, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight());
        setPosition(x, y);
        setOrigin(x, y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit with your Bunker class appended? Or does it just extend Sprite?

Answer (score 0):

The method sprite.draw can be seen from the libgdx source to do the following:

```
batch.draw(texture, getVertices(), 0, SPRITE_SIZE);
```

In all reality it would be more efficient to run it with `batch.draw(bunker, ...` since you wouldn't be invoking the getVertices() method.

EDIT:

I may have spoke too soon on which is more efficient, SpriteBatch will end up deriving the vertices for you when you invoke batch.draw(). sprite.draw() should be better since the vertices are already calculated and only get recalculated when the sprite is dirty. 
If you were to find out where the sprite is being drawn by calling bunker.getVertices() and outputting to the log you could see if it's just being drawn outside of the viewport.

Comment: I posted the getVertices() in the questions. It didn't seem to lead me anywhere.

Comment: Those vertices look strange, it appears to be drawing a polygon rather than a rectangle and the u v coordinates are all zero, I'll have to look into those more.

Answer (score 0):

Add this in GameObject's costructor
`super(image);`
instead of 
`setTexture(image);`